# How to reload rootViewController from appDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, rootview

I have a UINavigationController and on it I load a rootView that controlls the login process to my application.

I have recently added some code to my application delegate that checks my settings bundle for a logout request when this logout request happens I would like to either reload the rootView so that it loads the login hud, or just call the method inside rootView that shows the login hud.

This is how I set up the rootView for the navigationController inside my appdelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController; //Adds RootViewController to the NavigationController interface
    // etc
}
```

What I would like to know is there a way to reload rootViewController? or call a method from it inside the application delegate?

Comment: To call a method inside another controller you can use the delegate pattern, the target/action pattern, or the notification pattern. Read up on how all of them work, specifically in iOS/OS X, to determine which is best to use (you're doing iOS but it's the same on OS X and better documentation is available there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done but it's complicated. Best to avoid it if possible, and the specific requirements will be different for every app. Without seeing the source code for your app we can't tell you how it's done.

The basic process is you need to remove all of them from the view and set all references to nil, and then re-create it either from code or by loading the nib again.

A far better option is to leave the `rootViewController` where it is, and present a modal login view controller over the top of it. Once the user has logged in, send an `NSNotification` that the root view controller can observe, and populate its data.

Wait until after the notification has been sent to hide the login controller, and consider having the root view controller block the main thread while it performs any network operations pertaining to logging in. This way the login view (with a "logging in..." message?) will remain visible until the root view is fully populated.

Comment: okay.. this dose make alot more sense.. Thankyou for your reply.

Comment: The hard part is setting all references to nil. There are a lot of references, including some you may not know exist.

Comment: right.. I think your idea of haveing a dedicated view for loggin in/out is the smartest bet. the reason I implemented it in my root view initally was because I never though I would be showing the user the login screen again and also I didnt know this limitation existed.

Comment: @HurkNburkS I had exactly the same problem 6 months ago. ;)